# if $|AB|=0$, $A$ and $B$ are not zero matrix. what can i say about their ranks?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

as the title suggests.
$|AB|=0$ and i know that both $A$ and $B$ are not the the zero matrix. 
i want to prove that $Rank(A)$ and $Rank(B)$ cannot be full. specificly that their $Det$ is $0$.
is it even true? i will appriciate and help.

Comment: What does $|C|=0$ mean, rather than $C=0?$

Comment: Yes indeed true and at least one of the dets is zero. The second rank might be full!

Comment: Yes, if $\det(AB)=0$ then at least one of the ranks is not full.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you might have $A$ an $n \times m$ matrix and $B$ an $m \times n$ matrix, where $m < n$.  $A$ and $B$ could have rank $m$ (so both "full" in the sense of the largest possible rank for matrices of their dimensions), but $AB$ has rank at most $m$ and thus determinant $0$.

It's also possible in the case where $m > n$.  For example, 
$$ A = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 1 & 1\cr},\ B = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr 0 & -1\cr},\ AB = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr} $$

But it's true if you're talking about square matrices ($n \times n$).

Comment: Very nice! ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Well, if $A$ and $B$ are both square, than since

$$\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B),$$ at least one of the determinants will be zero.

If one of these has determinant zero, the other could have any rank, even full rank.  Here is an example:

$$A=\pmatrix{0 &0\\1&0}, \quad B=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}.$$